# Flexslider arrows dropped below the slide w extra white space

Tags: jquery, html, css

I plugged in the Flexslider2 into my website but for some reason the arrows keep dropping down to the bottom causing a strip of white space across the bottom of the photo. I have replaced the code back to the original from the download several times but this problem keeps happening. You can see it live at http://charvinedesign.com/bvd/ I'd be so grateful if someone can please help me figure this out? I've spent too much time on this.

```
HTML
    <div class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd001.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire" /></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd002.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd003.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd004.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire"/></li>
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd005.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire"/></li>   
    <li><img src="images/slider/bvd006.jpg" alt="Bear Valley Derby & Country Faire"/></li> 
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-direction-nav {
  *height: 0;
}
.flex-direction-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: -20px 0 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.flex-direction-nav a:before {
  font-family: "flexslider-icon";
  font-size: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
  content: '\f001';
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
.flex-direction-nav a.flex-next:before {
  content: '\f002';
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  left: -50px;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  right: -50px;
  text-align: right;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev {
  opacity: 0.7;
  left: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-prev:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
  opacity: 0.7;
  right: 10px;
}
.flexslider:hover .flex-direction-nav .flex-next:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.flex-direction-nav .flex-disabled {
  opacity: 0!important;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not using `flex-control-nav` (viz for pagination) you can add `display:none` to this further for the `flex-direction-nav` (viz for prev-next button) you can edit its `CSS` as for vertically middle its postion:

```
.flex-direction-nav {
   margin: 0px auto;
   text-align: center;
   width: 100%;
   left: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 40%;
   height: 50px;
 }
```

further for the `nav-arrows` you have to write `CSS` for them too.

Like as:

```
.flex-nav-prev {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    left: -15px;
 }

.flex-nav-next {
   position: absolute;
   top: 25px;
   right: -10px;
 }
```

and it will remove the white space and also positioned the `navs` where you want.

Comment: Thanks! That worked great for the white space but when you roll over the slider the arrows are still at the bottom of the slider. See it here: http://charvinedesign.com/bvd/  Any suggestions for that?

Comment: @Char , It will be more helpful if you tell me exactly where you want to place them?

Comment: It would be great if they were on the sides halfway up like in the demo http://flexslider.woothemes.com/  Thanks a million!